# Search for a value in where clause from Serialized Array

Tags: php, sql

The title could be confusing, but I think my doubt is clear.

I'll explain. I'm doing this query:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE day = "'.$day.'" AND month = "'.$month.'" AND year = "'.$year.'" AND realizada = 0 AND colaborador = "What to put here?!"';
```

But the field "colaborador" is a serialized array.

One example, when I `print_r`the value of my array after unserialize it's something like this:

`Array ( [0] => l3gion [1] => Someone [2] => teste )`

Imagine that I want to search for "l3gion" in the previous Query, how can I do this?

Thank you.

l3gion

Comment: the answer is simple. **Never** store serialized data in the database. And buy your self a book on database basics.

Comment: Or if you do store serialized data, don't expect to be able to query individual elements of it using SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to query individual elements from your array, don't store the serialized array.  Store each element on an individual row in a child table, and associate it with the primary key value of your calendar table:

```
CREATE TABLE colaboradoras (
  calendar_id INT NOT NULL,
  colaborador VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (calendar_id) REFERENCES calendar(calendar_id)
);

INSERT INTO colaboradoras VALUES
(1234, 'l3gion'),
(1234, 'Someone'),
(1234, 'teste');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar AS c JOIN colaboradoras AS o 
              ON c.calendar_id = o.calendar_id
        WHERE c.day = $day AND c.month = $month AND c.year = $year 
          AND c.realizada = 0 AND o.colaborador = 'l3gion'";
```

This is the normalized approach.

If you must store the serialized array, you might check out [How FriendFeed Uses MySQL](http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql) to index "schemaless" data.  But that also involves creating new tables for the indexes.

If you really can't create any new tables or indexes, you can try to use `LIKE` or `REGEXP` but both of these solutions will be very inefficient and error-prone.

```
SELECT ... WHERE ... AND colaborador REGEXP '[[:<:]]s:6:\"l3gion\";'
```

You're screwed.

Comment: Because of you, I showed to him this topic and he accepted the changes!

Hurray! Thumbs Up for everyone!

Answer (score 4):

The short answer:  Don't serialize data into a database field.  That's what [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is for...

The long answer is it's going to be VERY difficult to do.  You could do a search for `colaborador LIKE '%"13gion"%'`...  You could write a regex to deal with it as well (And use MySQL's [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) expression)...

But the best solution is to not store serialized data in the database...

Comment: The best solution is not to serialize data which you'll be searching by. In some cases storing serialized data in DB is really good idea because DB beeing normalized could expand to too much tables.

Comment: @Kirzilla: I disagree.  It's VERY hard to edit by hand.  It's meaningless to anything but a PHP program.  I'd *possibly* concede to storing a JSON string, but not a serialized value...

Comment: @Kirzilla: Right, because we're running out of tables!

Comment: I've used serialization in my tables is it better to refactor the database architecture to multiple tables instead of serialized data? Also I tried to search through them with a LIKE operator and it seems to work fine (at least for now).

Answer (score -2):

> colaborador = "What to put here?!"

This code will deal with serialized and raw data, as well as array and plain string values.

```
if (is_string($colaborador)) {
    // prevent errors from showing
    ob_start();
    $data = unserialize($colaborador);
    // $data is now false or output buffer is non-empty if $colaborador was
    // not serialized
    $data = ob_get_length() > 0 || false === $data ? $colaborador : $data;
    // lose the possible error
    ob_end_clean();
} else {
    $data = $colaborador;
}
// use the first value as colaborador if an array
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE day = "'.$day.'" AND month = "'.$month.'"
AND year = "'.$year.'" AND realizada = 0 AND colaborador = \'' .
(is_array($data) ? (empty($data) ? '' : $data[0]) : $data) . '\'';`
```

Or if you want to search all of them:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE day = "'.$day.'" AND month = "'.$month.'"
AND year = "'.$year.'" AND realizada = 0 AND colaborador = IN (\'' .
(is_array($data) ? (empty($data) ? '' : implode("', '", $data[0])) : $data) . '\')';`
```

Comment: Besides the horrors of using an output buffer to try to detect errors from unserialization, he was asking about searching a serialized value in the database, not using a serialized value as the text to search...

Comment: @ircmaxell: That's about the only way to catch unserialize failure when error reporting is on (the default case, and propably the situation for l3gion). Searching for the serialized data was how I read the question.

Comment: you can do it with `$php_errormsg`...  `$php_errormsg = ''; $data = @unserialize($foo);  $data = empty($php_errormsg) ? $data : $foo;`  Or, even better would be using error exceptions.  But please don't abuse output buffering like that (it's only going to make maintenance almost impossible)...

Comment: @ircmaxell: unserialize issues an E_NOTICE, which is printed to the browser. This is unless you change the default settings. Output buffering is needed to catch that. If you're clever enough to reduce error_reporting, you're clever enough to understand that in your case you don't need output buffering.